# How to insert a filter in my EditText in a ListView to filter my Database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-edittext, searchable

I have a ListView with an EditText to prompt a simple query making a select in my database, and i need to implements this query in my TextWatcher {... but I don't know how to do that any ideas ??

And I need to query two columns in one table...

```
public class ListaMateriais extends Activity {

private ListView listamateriais;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapMatchMaterial;
EditText inputSearch;
public EditText ETclient; 
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_material_match);

    String products[] = { "Parafuso 3x4 092387",
                      "Cabeçote redpo 09873",  
                      "alavanca de ignição 027625", 
                      "Pistão de arranque 093298092",  
                      "Eixo dianteiro 0343232", 
                      "Cabeçote parafuseta 093232" }; 
    listamateriais = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_match_material);
    adapMatchMaterial = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
    listamateriais.setAdapter(adapMatchMaterial);

    listamateriais.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,  long arg3) {
            String text= (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("TextMateriais", text);
            Intent int_material = new Intent(ListaMateriais.this,Formulario_ItemNota.class);
            int_material.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(int_material);
            finish();
        } 
    }); 

    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.materialSearch); 
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            ListaMateriais.this.adapMatchMaterial.getFilter().filter(cs);
        } 
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        } 
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Any helps will be truly appreciated... Thanks

Comment: You can use AutoCompleteTextView for this purpose.

Comment: how can i do that, and i can take the value of this AutoCompleteTextView ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AutoCompleteTextView`

```
AutoCompleteTextView atxtSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.atxtSearchUser);
atxtSearch.setThreshold(3);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapMatchMaterial = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,products); //products should be an array
atxtSearch.setAdapter(adapMatchMaterial );
```

Then When you type on this edit text, after typing 3 letters, it will automatically list the items

Answer (score 2):

you need to create a custom adpater that will extends Filter,

try this tutorial:
http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html

Then in performFiltering, you can query the database to get the data and refresh you list.

```
ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(mCursor.moveToFirst(); !mCursor.isAfterLast(); mCursor.moveToNext()) {
    // The Cursor is now set to the right position
    mArrayList.add(mCursor.getString(COLUMN_INDEX_YOU_WANT));
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry i just forgot to change my code, in that way it's working fine, but i will query a local db instead, i will try ur solution tomorrow and see what's going on...

Comment: And by the way, in this specific case, i will have a table with more than 40.000 k, of materials so what i need to do ? it's implements a searchable list view that the user will prompt what they wants, till there okay, but thinking about performance a list view with 40k i don't think will be really fast, neither i don't now if my device will support this, so can you tell me if i can show only what i'm typing instead everytime loads the entire list ??

Comment: do u think just an EditText with a ListView it's okay to this new solution, or to works better i need to implements also a Button to filter especifically what i wants and show in the ListView to pick that item ?? because i will filter by the name and Code, so the user don't need to see all the time the list, do you know what i mean ?

Comment: To optimize the db search:    
- I would only search if the user enters minimum 3 characters.    
- Use listview with pagination limited to 30 elements, if the user scroll down fecth more, so you need to include this in your query

Comment: you can find plenty of libraries to handle pagination list on github like this one https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews